# extracting the array value from the hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this hash

```
data = {"05 INTERNAL":[["5e Research","66"]],"06 MISCELLANEOUS":[["6a Internal Training","69"]]}
```

I want to get the value of the first key in the array.
when I do

```
Object.values(data)[0]
```

I get an array which consists of

```
[["5e Research","66"]]
```

How do I extract the value `"66"` from this using jquery?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Object.values(data)[0][0][1]

Comment: That's not a _hash_ it's a _map_. A "hashMap" is _one_ particular way to _implement_ a map, but not all maps are hashmaps. (...) and what's with `[["5e Research","66"]]` - that is an Array with one element: an Array of two strings. Why not just a single level `["5e Research","66"]` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can reference a property with `string`, like that:

```js
const data = {
  "05 INTERNAL": [
    ["5e Research", "66"]
  ],
  "06 MISCELLANEOUS": [
    ["6a Internal Training", "69"]
  ]
}

console.log(data['05 INTERNAL'][0][1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {"05 INTERNAL":[["5e Research","66"]],"06 MISCELLANEOUS":[["6a Internal Training","69"]]};
```

The answer is:

```
data['05 INTERNAL'][0][1];
```